Film similar to Rollerball
Caught part of this in between falling asleep on the couch late night, and couldn't find the name on the index list a couple days later, so hoping y'all can help me.
Theme: Similar to Rollerball, in that there are teams that either fight each other or dogs, not sure. I remember one uniform looked kind of like layered leather, with a large club. Rollerballesque in that there were moneyed guys running the teams in a post apocalyptic type world. Seemed vaguely reminiscent of the way rugby is played.
Color: Yes, in a filming style reminiscent of the early 1990's. 
Language: English, not subtitled or accented to my ear or that I remember, so I am guessing it was a US production.
Live Action: Yes. One of the actors seemed familiar, but in the foggy state I was in I couldn't identify him, so probably a name but not a premier A lister.

Curious because it might help... do you know what channel and date it was on?

@Catija - Don't remember channel, but it was on DirecTV, western US geography, sometime around Sep/Oct of last year (2016).
